# Using grep to find CRITICAL vulnerabilities in report file

Tags: security, grep, scanning

I wonder if you can help... I'm currently implementing container scanning on one of my images in Gitlab and want to use grep to search for any CRITICAL vulnerabilities.

So far I have the below but the problem is, with the report it mentions CRITICAL then the number of vulnerabilities found whereas I was hoping to ignore that and look for where it mentions CRITICAL under SEVERITY.

I guess ideally i'd want the grep to work if it found CRITICAL > 0 under the total row but i'm not sure how to do this with grep so any help appreciated!

Code:

```
 if cat REPORT.txt | grep -e 'CRITICAL'; then 
    echo 'Critical vulnerability found -- fail build' currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE' 
  else
    echo 'All Good'
  fi
```

Report example:

```
Total: 2 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 1, MEDIUM: 1, HIGH: 0, CRITICAL: 0)

+------------------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|           LIBRARY            |  VULNERABILITY ID   | SEVERITY |    INSTALLED VERSION     |      FIXED VERSION       |                            TITLE                             |
+------------------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| apt                          | CVE-2020-3810       | MEDIUM   | 1.4.9                    | 1.4.10                   | Missing input validation in                                  |
|                              |                     |          |                          |                          | the ar/tar implementations of                                |
|                              |                     |          |                          |                          | APT before version 2.1.2...                                  |
+                              +---------------------+----------+                          +--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              | CVE-2011-3374       | LOW      |                          |                          | It was found that apt-key                                    |
|                              |                     |          |                          |                          | in apt, all versions, do not                                 |
|                              |                     |          |                          |                          | correctly...                                                 |
+------------------------------+---------------------+          +--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return only lines where CRITICAL appears in the column under SEVERITY, try:

```
awk -F'|' '$4 ~ /CRITICAL/' reports.txt
```

awk reads input files one line at a time and breaks each line into fields.  `-F'|'` tells awk to use `|` as the field separator.  Consequently, the SEVERITY column is the fourth field and `$4 ~ /CRITICAL/` tests to see if that field containst CRITICAL.

#### Example

Consider this input file (which has one CRITICAL that we want and several that we want to ignore):

```
$ cat reports.txt

+------------------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|           LIBRARY            |  VULNERABILITY ID   | SEVERITY |    INSTALLED VERSION     |      FIXED VERSION       |                            TITLE                             |
+------------------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| apt-CRITICAL                 | CVE-2020-3810       | MEDIUM   | 1.4.9                    | 1.4.10                   | Missing input validation in                                  |
|                              |                     |          | CRITICAL                 |                          | the ar/tar implementations of-CRITICAL                       |
|                              |                     |          |                          |                          | APT before version 2.1.2...                                  |
+                              +---------------------+----------+                          +--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              | CVE-2011-3374       | CRITICAL |                          |                          | It was found that apt-key                                    |
|                              |                     |          |                          |                          | in apt, all versions, do not                                 |
|                              |                     |          |                          |                          | correctly...                                                 |
+------------------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Our command correctly returns only the line with the CRITICAL severity:

```
$ awk -F'|' '$4 ~ /CRITICAL/' reports.txt
|                              | CVE-2011-3374       | CRITICAL |                          |                          | It was found that apt-key
```

#### Use in an if-statement

We can use awk to set the correct exit-code so that it works correctly in an `if` statement while producing no extraneous output:

```
if awk -F'|' -v c=1 '$4 ~ /CRITICAL/{c=0; exit} END{exit c}' reports.txt; then
```